# How to sum all of the values in the input sequence in parallel?

Tags: scala

I'm working on this function that should sum all of the values in the input sequence in parallel way to take advantage of multiple cores.

Code:

```
def paraSum(list: scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq[Int]): Int = ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `sum`:

```
val source = (1 to 2000000).par
source.sum
```

If you need to use your `parallelSum` you should lock the `accumulator` when accessing to it to protect your code against race conditions between the threads running `map`:

```
def parallelSum(list: scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq[Int]): Int = {
    var accumulator = 0
    list.foreach(x => synchronized(accumulator += x))
    accumulator
}
```

But I don't think that's the best approach.

Comment: @progx You are wellcome. Btw, since you are using `map` to apply a function to all `list` elements just for its side effects, `foreach` is more apropiate

Answer (score 1):

Use `aggregate` on a parallel version of the collection, and define the combining operation as the sum of intermediate sums, for instance like this,

```
xs.par.aggregate(0)(_+_,_+_)
```

Note `+` on `Int` is associative and commutative hence we can combine (sum up) intermediate summations in parallel. In the expression above the first `+` produces intermediate additions, the second combines then (in parallel).